# Why memset init partially?

Tags: c

I'm trying to init a `int **a` with 0 by `memset`. But the result is some item is not zero.
**Source code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <memory.h>

int main()
{
    int aSize = 3;
    int **a = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int *)*aSize);
    for (int i=0; i<aSize; i++) {
        a[i]=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*aSize);
    }

    memset(a[0], 0, aSize*aSize*sizeof(int));

    for (int i=0; i<aSize; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<aSize; j++) {
            printf("%d ", a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
0 0 0 
0 0 0 
0 1610612736 0
```

---

**Update 1**

I'm trying to `malloc` contiugous in two ways as suggested. But in method 2 a exception thrown when init array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h> // memset header changed
// method 1
int **a = malloc(sizeof(int *)*aSize);
for (int i=0; i<aSize; i++) {
    a[i]=malloc(sizeof(int)*aSize);
    memset(a[i], 0, aSize*sizeof(int));
}

for (int i=0; i<aSize; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<aSize; j++) {
        printf("%d ", a[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

for (int i=0; i<aSize; i++) {
    free(a[i]);
}

free(a);

// method 2
a = malloc(sizeof(int *)*aSize + sizeof(int)*aSize);
memset(a[0], 0, aSize*aSize*sizeof(int)); // Exception: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x1c)
```

Comment: Use `calloc` instead of `malloc` and `memset`. It clears the memory for you.

Comment: Moreover, if you want to allocate a 2D array dynamically that has contiguous memory. There are ways for that as well.

Comment: `a[0]` is only `sizeof(int)*aSize` bytes, you cannot `memset(a[0], 0, aSize*aSize*sizeof(int));`. There is no guarantee any of the blocks of memory for `a[0]` -> `a[aSize-1]` are contiguous. There is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `memset` line assumes that the array of pointers created in your first `for` loop point to **contiguous** memory - that is, you assume that, for example, `a[1]` will point to the memory location immediately following the buffer pointed to by `a[0]`.

However, there is no ***guarantee*** that this will be the case! As it happens, in some of your cases this is true but, ultimately, working on this assumption will cause ***Undefined Behaviour***!

To correct the problem, you should initialize each memory buffer separately; the simplest way would be to do it as your create each one:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <memory.h>

int main()
{
    int aSize = 3;
    int **a = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int *)*aSize);
    for (int i=0; i<aSize; i++) {
        a[i]=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*aSize);
         memset(a[i], 0, aSize*sizeof(int)); // Set each buffer to all zeros here!
    }

//  memset(a[0], 0, aSize*aSize*sizeof(int)); // This will cause undefined behaviour

    for (int i=0; i<aSize; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<aSize; j++) {
            printf("%d ", a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Feel free to ask for further clarification and/or explanation.

Answer (score 3):

This cannot possibly work other than by amazing fluke:

```
memset(a[0], 0, aSize*aSize*sizeof(int));
```

You have simulated a multi-dimensional array by allocating a vector of pointers to separately allocated rows. But in the above expression, you're assuming that the memory is linear (allocated all in one piece). The `memset` writes beyond the end of the `a[0]` row, causing undefined behavior.

The correct approach is to iterate over the array of pointers, and individually `memset` each row:

```
for (i = 0; i < aSize; i++)
   memset(a[i], 0, aSize * sizeof a[i]);
```

This `memset` action can be hoisted into the original loop which allocates the rows; moreover, `calloc` can be used instead of `malloc` to make the `memset` unnecessary.  (The C language requires that an all-zero bit memory pattern produces values of zero when interpreted as a numeric type such as `int` or `double`, so initializing numeric arrays to zero with `calloc` is type safe and portable.)

Also, there is no `<memory.h>` header in standard C. The `malloc` function has been declared in `<stdlib.h>` since before C was first standardized in 1989.